# Unable to include array in arduinoIDE

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, stl, stdarray

I know that C++ arduino is a little bit different from the C++ we know, in the sense that only a subset of C++ functionalities are usable on an Arduino platform. But there's ArduinoSTL, that's an arduino library that makes it possible to use some C++ data structures such as arrays.
I've been trying to use std::array on arduino without success. I get the following error message:

> array: No such file or directory

Here's my code

```
#include<ArduinoSTL.h>
#include<array>

const std::array< std::array<bool, 5>, 3 > Z= {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
```

I tried to remove `#include<array>`, remove `std::`, without success. **What am I missing?**

Comment: Sounds like you have something not configured correctly in your include directory structure.  Make sure in the settings on the IDE that the folder where `<array>` is located is listed as one of the paths to search for include files.

Comment: @NathanOliver Actually there's no trace of array in the include folder, there's valarray (which I've never heard of), vector, algorithm and the all the rest but no array... I installed ArduinoSTL 1.1 using the ArduinoIDE, maybe that's not the latest version of ArduinoSTL

Comment: Not sure.  I see it exists here: https://github.com/mike-matera/ArduinoSTL/tree/master/src

Comment: @NathanOliver I copied the content of the src folder of the repo to the right place in the working directory of ArduinoIDE and the error message is gone. Thanks.